# Insert into generated list in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

At the moment I have this list

```
List.generate(72, (index) {
    retrun Container(
        child: new Text('$index'),
    )
})
```

as the `children` of a `GridView` widget. What I however would like to do is return a different value than the `$index` for certain index values.

For this I have a List that looks like `[{index: 2, value: test}{index: 5, value: hello}]` with a lot of index/value pairs. So here is the question:

Is there a way now to display the value from the list in the `GridView` field if the matching index is in the list and if it is not simply return  `$index`?

Just as an example, the field with the index `1` in the `GridView` should display its index, so it displays `1`. The field with the index `2` however should display the matching value from the list, which is `test` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should preprocess the list into a `Map`. If necessary, iterate the list adding each entry to a map.

Then you can:

```
  Map m = <int, String>{
    2: 'test',
    5: 'hello',
  };
  List<Container>.generate(72, (int index) {
    String s = m[index];
    return Container(
      child: Text(s != null ? s : '$index'),
    );
  });
```

or, more succinctly with the null aware operator

```
  List<Container>.generate(
    72,
    (int index) => Container(child: Text(m[index] ?? '$index')),
  );
```